# SSRS insert specific vale from a dataset

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I'm new to SQL and SSRS. I'm facing the following problem - here the database (simplified):

```
Office  Hours   Year  Quarter  
  A       3     2020     1
  B       6     2020     2
  C       9     2020     1
  D       11    2020     2
  E       5     2020     2
  OX      20    2020     1
```

I have alredy created a Marix that groups Quarters and shows the hours for every Office, except the last one, and has a column in which calculates the percentage of hours on the total, excluding the last office (fo example office A has 3 hours of 34 so 8.823% , office B has 6 of 34 so 17.647% and so on...
What I'm trying to achieve is create a table like the one below:

```
OX Allocation |    qt 
------------------------
      A          1.764 
      B          3.528
```

so allocating the hour of OX in every other office.

But i'm honest I'm unable to do that, I dont know how to start also selecting the specific value of the Office OX (20)
I know that is not perfectly correct the aspect of quarters, but what I need is to understand how to isolate the specific value in a column and do the calcuation for the allocation

thanks in advance!

EDIT: Sorry I add the explanation of the percentual in second table.
(I have also correct a numeric error)

20 * (8.823/100) = 1.764  (for Office A)
20 * (17.647/100) = 3.528  (for Office B)

Comment: It's not clear what calculation you are trying to do. How do you get A = 1.646 ? Is is 8.823% of 20 hours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this in SQL (it's usually easier to do this kind of things in the dataset query rather than using SSRS expressions) then you can do something like this

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(Office varchar(2), Hours decimal (10,6), Year int , Quarter int)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES 
('A' ,  3, 2020, 1),
('B' ,  6, 2020, 2),
('C' ,  9, 2020, 1),
('D' , 11, 2020, 2),
('E' ,  5, 2020, 2),
('OX', 20, 2020, 1)

SELECT 
    a.*
    , a.pc * o.[Hours] as OxAllocation
 FROM 
    (
    SELECT 
        *
        , pc = Hours /SUM(Hours) OVER()
        FROM @t
        WHERE Office != 'OX'
    ) a 
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT * FROM @t WHERE Office = 'OX') o
```

This will give the following results

[image]